# Why does Android Studio create the ic_launcher_foreground in res/drawable-v24 and the ic_launcher_background.xml in res/drawable?

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, android-vectordrawable, adaptive-icon

**Firstly**

I noticed when creating a new project in Android Studio it generates `drawable-v24` folder with `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` icon.

And my question is:

1. If **vector drawable**s were introduced before v24 then why does it put the vector asset in `drawable-v24` and not in `drawable-v21` folder?

---

**Secondly**

Another generated asset is `ic_launcher_background.xml` which is created in `res/drawable` folder and was later referenced from `mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml`.

2. If it is only used in API v26+ ([adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)) then why was it created in `res/drawable` folder and not in `res/drawable-v24` or in `res/drawable-v26`? Is it due to some nature of mipmap folders?

Comment: Did you find this answer ever?

Answer (score 2):

The [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources) feature is somewhat integrated in API-24 though it was introduced from API-21. I think Google's developers think API-24+ is ideal or stable for adaptive icons.

For example, Nick Butcher (Android designer + developer @ Google) said in his article: [Using vector assets in Android apps](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/using-vector-assets-in-android-apps-4318fd662eb9) (Dec 11, 2018),

> - Both nonZero and evenOdd path fillTypes —the two common ways of defining the inside of a shape, often used in SVGs (evenOdd added to platform impl in API 24)
> - Gradient & ColorStateList fills/strokes (added to platform impl in API 24)

And about `ic_launcher_background`, it is referenced only from `mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml` and `mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml`. I think it is just that there is no need to prevent from referencing it directly (It has already prevented by placing `ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml` in `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder). There should be not so far more, deep meanings.

Answer (score 2):

A [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-change-app-icon#5) answers your questions.

> Depending on the min SDK of your app, you may notice that the foreground asset is located in the drawable-v24 folder, while the background asset is in the drawable folder. The reason is because the foreground asset contains a gradient, which was available starting in the Android 7.0 release (also known as API version 24, hence the -v24 resource qualifier). The background asset doesn't contain a gradient, so that can go in the base drawable folder.

As a side note, though we generally don't use `ic_launcher_background.xml` for any purpose other than the app icon, it is just a vector drawable and its usage is not limited.